# Code Igniter and Error Handlers

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling, web

Can someone point me to the right direction?
I just want the error page to show if things like this happen.

[image: Sample Error]

I dont know where to begin. Please help!

Comment: undefined index article_title you may have miss spelled it in controller or view. Next time paste code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your logging level in index.php from `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` notices and warnings will be suppressed. Good practice dictates that we develop with notices and warnings enabled but in production these would be suppressed and your code will still work. Its up to you whether you bother about them. Only errors of type E_ERROR will fatally break your code